# 504 Gateway timeout & mysql connection error repeating regularly

Tags: php, mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

504 Gateway timeout & mysql connection error repeating regularly. It repeats itself every 2-3 hours. The server either shuts down OR takes too much time to respond causing Gateway error (504 & 502) OR the files are not able to connect to the Database.

Can anyone help me diagnose & fix the issue? I have tried to troubleshoot the issue but I am not able to fix it. I am really depending on the Stackoverflow community for help.

My application & database are hosted on AWS EC2 & RDS resp. I have included the major troubleshooting steps I have taken below.

Here's what I have done till now

1. Check CPU utilisation for my EC2 instance. It seems normal

[image]

2. I was getting this error on cloudwatch. "[Warning] IP address 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx' could not be resolved: Name or service not known" & "InnoDB: 96 redo rollback segment(s) found. 96 redo rollback segment(s) are active" Based on the answers here https://serverfault.com/questions/393862/mysql-warning-ip-address-could-not-be-resolved and https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/192713/mysql-ibdata1-is-broken, I changed my my.cnf file.

Old File

```
[mysqld]
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock

# Disabling symbolic-links is recommended to prevent assorted security risks
symbolic-links=0
# Settings user and group are ignored when systemd is used.
# If you need to run mysqld under a different user or group,
# customize your systemd unit file for mysqld according to the
# instructions in http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Systemd

[mysqld_safe]
log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
```

New File

```
[mysqld]
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
# Skip reverse DNS lookup 
skip-name-resolve
# Disabling symbolic-links is recommended to prevent assorted security risks
symbolic-links=0
# Settings user and group are ignored when systemd is used.
# If you need to run mysqld under a different user or group,
# customize your systemd unit file for mysqld according to the
# instructions in http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Systemd
innodb_buffer_pool_size=512M

[mysqld_safe]
log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
```

3. I made changes to my php.ini file to increase

   Maximum amount of memory a script may consume (512MB)
   http://php.net/memory-limit
   memory_limit = 512M
4. Changed the max_allowed_packet in aws->rds-> parameters from default to 68719476 at UTC time 09:34 am

Latest log of Cloudwatch is mentioned below (after restarting the server at ~06:30:00 UTC) is as below

```
2021-01-18T06:24:24.223693Z 20568 [Note] Aborted connection 20568 to db: 'xxx' user: 'yyy' host: 'aaa.bb.c.dd' (Got an error reading communication packets)
2021-01-18T06:25:25.234503Z 20571 [Note] Aborted connection 20571 to db: 'xxx' user: 'yyy' host: 'aaa.bb.c.dd' (Got timeout reading communication packets)
2021-01-18T06:34:24.135251Z 20908 [Note] Aborted connection 20908 to db: 'xxx' user: 'yyy' host: 'aaa.bb.c.dd' (Got an error reading communication packets)
2021-01-18T06:34:25.083554Z 20910 [Note] Aborted connection 20910 to db: 'xxx' user: 'yyy' host: 'aaa.bb.c.dd' (Got an error reading communication packets)
2021-01-18T06:36:24.203213Z 18859 [Note] Aborted connection 18859 to db: 'unconnected' user: 'rdsadmin' host: 'localhost' (Got an error reading communication packets)
2021-01-18T06:44:25.529027Z 21649 [Note] Aborted connection 21649 to db: 'xxx' user: 'yyy' host: 'aaa.bb.c.dd' (Got an error reading communication packets)
2021-01-18T06:44:54.170674Z 21404 [Note] Aborted connection 21404 to db: 'unconnected' user: 'rdsadmin' host: 'localhost' (Got an error reading communication packets)
2021-01-18T06:44:54.414084Z 21648 [Note] Aborted connection 21648 to db: 'xxx' user: 'yyy' host: 'aaa.bb.c.dd' (Got an error reading communication packets)
2021-01-18T06:54:39.033933Z 22763 [Warning] IP address 'ppp.qq.rrr.sss' could not be resolved: Name or service not known
2021-01-18T06:54:39.067858Z 22763 [Note] Access denied for user 'OFJoGcFk'@'ppp.qq.rrr.sss' (using password: YES)
2021-01-18T06:54:39.133733Z 22764 [Note] Access denied for user 'root'@'ppp.qq.rrr.sss' (using password: YES)
2021-01-18T06:54:39.236118Z 22765 [Note] Access denied for user 'root'@'ppp.qq.rrr.sss' (using password: YES)
2021-01-18T06:54:39.310352Z 22766 [Note] Access denied for user 'root'@'ppp.qq.rrr.sss' (using password: YES)
2021-01-18T06:54:39.378335Z 22767 [Note] Access denied for user 'root'@'ppp.qq.rrr.sss' (using password: YES)
2021-01-18T06:54:39.446096Z 22768 [Note] Access denied for user 'root'@'ppp.qq.rrr.sss' (using password: YES)
2021-01-18T06:54:39.547281Z 22769 [Note] Access denied for user 'root'@'ppp.qq.rrr.sss' (using password: YES)
2021-01-18T06:54:39.649926Z 22770 [Note] Access denied for user 'root'@'ppp.qq.rrr.sss' (using password: YES)
2021-01-18T06:54:39.752436Z 22771 [Note] Access denied for user 'root'@'ppp.qq.rrr.sss' (using password: YES)
2021-01-18T06:54:39.855066Z 22772 [Note] Access denied for user 'root'@'ppp.qq.rrr.sss' (using password: YES)
2021-01-18T06:54:39.960074Z 22773 [Note] Access denied for user 'root'@'ppp.qq.rrr.sss' (using password: YES)
2021-01-18T06:54:40.034008Z 22774 [Note] Access denied for user 'root'@'ppp.qq.rrr.sss' (using password: YES)
2021-01-18T06:54:40.100103Z 22775 [Note] Access denied for user 'root'@'ppp.qq.rrr.sss' (using password: NO)
2021-01-18T06:54:40.209419Z 22776 [Note] Access denied for user 'root'@'ppp.qq.rrr.sss' (using password: YES)
2021-01-18T06:54:40.316418Z 22777 [Note] Access denied for user 'root'@'ppp.qq.rrr.sss' (using password: YES)
2021-01-18T06:54:40.386682Z 22779 [Note] Access denied for user 'root'@'ppp.qq.rrr.sss' (using password: YES)
2021-01-18T06:54:40.497650Z 22780 [Note] Access denied for user 'root'@'ppp.qq.rrr.sss' (using password: YES)
2021-01-18T06:54:40.602995Z 22781 [Note] Access denied for user 'root'@'ppp.qq.rrr.sss' (using password: YES)
2021-01-18T06:54:40.674457Z 22782 [Note] Access denied for user 'root'@'ppp.qq.rrr.sss' (using password: YES)
2021-01-18T06:54:40.786216Z 22783 [Note] Access denied for user 'root'@'ppp.qq.rrr.sss' (using password: YES)
2021-01-18T06:54:40.891323Z 22784 [Note] Access denied for user 'username'@'ppp.qq.rrr.sss' (using password: YES)
2021-01-18T06:54:40.960942Z 22785 [Note] Access denied for user 'jamfsoftware'@'ppp.qq.rrr.sss' (using password: YES)
2021-01-18T06:54:41.034156Z 22786 [Note] Access denied for user 'admin@example.com'@'ppp.qq.rrr.sss' (using password: YES)
2021-01-18T06:54:41.109989Z 22788 [Note] Access denied for user 'superdba'@'ppp.qq.rrr.sss' (using password: YES)
2021-01-18T06:54:41.185671Z 22789 [Note] Access denied for user 'root'@'ppp.qq.rrr.sss' (using password: YES)
2021-01-18T06:54:41.262527Z 22790 [Note] Access denied for user 'admin'@'ppp.qq.rrr.sss' (using password: YES)
2021-01-18T06:54:41.369667Z 22791 [Note] Access denied for user 'admin'@'ppp.qq.rrr.sss' (using password: YES)
2021-01-18T06:54:41.470788Z 22792 [Note] Access denied for user 'admin'@'ppp.qq.rrr.sss' (using password: YES)
2021-01-18T06:54:41.570520Z 22793 [Note] Access denied for user 'user'@'ppp.qq.rrr.sss' (using password: YES)
2021-01-18T06:54:41.636878Z 22794 [Note] Access denied for user 'user'@'ppp.qq.rrr.sss' (using password: YES)
2021-01-18T06:54:41.707041Z 22795 [Note] Access denied for user 'user'@'ppp.qq.rrr.sss' (using password: YES)
2021-01-18T06:54:41.817872Z 22796 [Note] Access denied for user 'test'@'ppp.qq.rrr.sss' (using password: YES)
2021-01-18T06:54:41.925845Z 22797 [Note] Access denied for user 'test'@'ppp.qq.rrr.sss' (using password: YES)
2021-01-18T06:54:42.026637Z 22798 [Note] Access denied for user 'test'@'ppp.qq.rrr.sss' (using password: YES)
2021-01-18T06:54:42.091489Z 22799 [Note] Access denied for user 'mysql'@'ppp.qq.rrr.sss' (using password: YES)
2021-01-18T06:54:42.200321Z 22802 [Note] Access denied for user 'mysql'@'ppp.qq.rrr.sss' (using password: YES)
2021-01-18T06:54:42.275979Z 22804 [Note] Access denied for user 'mysql'@'ppp.qq.rrr.sss' (using password: YES)
2021-01-18T07:12:19.419623Z 23525 [Note] Aborted connection 23525 to db: 'xxx' user: 'yyy' host: 'aaa.bb.c.dd' (Got an error reading communication packets)
2021-01-18T07:12:19.923527Z 23524 [Note] Aborted connection 23524 to db: 'xxx' user: 'yyy' host: 'aaa.bb.c.dd' (Got an error reading communication packets)
2021-01-18T07:21:30.013587Z 24109 [Note] Aborted connection 24109 to db: 'xxx' user: 'yyy' host: 'aaa.bb.c.dd' (Got an error reading communication packets)
2021-01-18T07:22:29.106513Z 24108 [Note] Aborted connection 24108 to db: 'xxx' user: 'yyy' host: 'aaa.bb.c.dd' (Got timeout reading communication packets)
2021-01-18T07:32:29.042482Z 24784 [Note] Aborted connection 24784 to db: 'xxx' user: 'yyy' host: 'aaa.bb.c.dd' (Got timeout reading communication packets)
2021-01-18T07:32:29.938504Z 24785 [Note] Aborted connection 24785 to db: 'xxx' user: 'yyy' host: 'aaa.bb.c.dd' (Got timeout reading communication packets)
2021-01-18T07:33:16.155955Z 25201 [Note] Aborted connection 25201 to db: 'xxx' user: 'yyy' host: 'eee.ff.g.hh' (Got an error reading communication packets)
2021-01-18T07:41:59.405239Z 25456 [Note] Aborted connection 25456 to db: 'xxx' user: 'yyy' host: 'zzz' (Got an error reading communication packets)
2021-01-18T07:42:00.220836Z 25457 [Note] Aborted connection 25457 to db: 'xxx' user: 'yyy' host: 'zzz' (Got an error reading communication packets
```

Comment: How much RAM is on your EC2 and RDS servers?  Could you post A) your complete php configuration files from your EC2  and RDS servers and from each server, B) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE '%timeout%'; C) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE '%timeout%'; D) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE '%aborted%'; E) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE 'uptime';  ? for analysis.

Comment: Could you also post from OS Command Prompt, results of  ulimit -a  from each server so we can see your limits?

Comment: Hey @WilsonHauck 
Thanks for your suggestion. I have increased my configuration on AWS and it seems to have been resolved. Thanks for the steps you suggested :)

Comment: Have a GREAT 2021! Stay Safe.